# Solving a for a function within a known definite integral?

Tags: calculus

I have a problem in my physics class which seems to boil down to $$\int_0^1 f(x)x \,dx = C$$ where $C$ is a constant and I need to solve for $f(x)$. If possible, I need the solutions where $$f(0)=0.$$ Is this solvable?

Comment: More conditions are needed.

Answer (score 0):

Pick $f(x)=Ax$ (where $A$ is a constant), then the integral evaluates to $A/2$. Therefore $f(x)=2Cx$ works.